# Setting limits for randomly generated positions for button

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a very simple app where you have a timer that counts down from 30 seconds and a button on the screen, and each time the button is clicked it "moves" (its x and y values are changed). I haven't implemented the timer part of the app yet since in the version I currently have the button sometimes "disappears". My guess is that it's being moved to a position out of the bounds of the device's screen and I can't figure out how to set the limits so the random x and y values of the button don't surpass the size of the screen so the button is always visible and therefore clickable as well.
My current MainActivity.kt code:

```
package com.example.button_chaser

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.DisplayMetrics
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlin.random.Random

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var button: Button
    lateinit var text: TextView
    var score = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        var text: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.score)

        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)

        var width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
        var height = displayMetrics.heightPixels

        println(width)
        println(height)

        button.setOnClickListener{
            score += 1
            text.text = "Score: $score"

            button.x = Random.nextInt(width).toFloat()
            button.y = Random.nextInt(height).toFloat()
        }

    }

}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/my_relativeLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Score"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Display metrics gives you the size of the whole screen, including the status bar, bottom system bar, etc. Depending on which settings the user has turned on, you may or may not have to try to find the heights of the system bars and selectively subtract them. This is very complicated and error prone.

You could get the height and width of your view, but not until after the scene has already been laid out, which hasn't happened yet in `onCreate()`. Even if you do that, you also have to keep in mind the size of the button itself so you don't pick a position that crops off its right or bottom edge. So that is also messy.

Instead, I would put the Button in a ConstraintLayout and constrain all four of its edges to the parent's edges. This will center it. Then you can modify `verticalBias` and `horizontalBias` to put it at a random position that fits in the view.

`verticalBias` and `horizontalBias` are a number between 0 and 1 that shifts a view between the extremes of its relevant constraints, so you can simply choose a random number between 0 and 1 to get a random position. You can use `Random.nextFloat()` to get a random number from 0 to 1.

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/myButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```kotlin
private fun randomizeButtonPosition() {
    button.layoutParams = (button.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
        horizontalBias = Random.nextFloat()
        verticalBias = Random.nextFloat()
    }
}
```

Note we are only modifying the existing LayoutParams instance that is set on the button, but we also have to reassign it back to the button anyway to make the ConstraintLayout aware that it needs to recompute the position.